# Incorrect redirect scheme in using nginx as reversed proxy

Tags: tomcat, redirect, nginx, https

I use nginx as front-end server and tomcat as back-end. The clients access my site via https scheme. For example:

```
https://example.com/app/test
```

Nginx receive this and pass the request to tomcat via this local address:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/test
```

My nginx config:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

This works fine. However, when I try to use redirect (http 302), it always turn https to http. This is my redirect code:

```
response.sendRedirect("/app/redirect-test");
```

What I expecting is to redirect the browser to:

```
https://example.com/app/redirect-test
```

but it always redirects the browser to:

```
http://example.com/app/redirect-test.
```

I also log the headers to track this issue:

```
host : example.com
x-real-ip : 180.168.202.246
x-forward-for : 180.168.202.246
x-forward-proto : https
connection : close
......
```

But I still cannot figure out. And I try to log request.getRequestURL(), then I get this result:

```
http://example.com/app/test
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I realized I make a mistake, X-Forward-For should be X-Forwarded-For
and X-Forward-Proto should be X-Forwarded-Proto. But after I fixed that, the issue still exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution.

nginx.conf

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Modify Tomcat's server.xml Host section

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<!-- blah blah blah -->
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https"/>
</Host>
```

Go to this place to see the detail: [Tomcat Doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html)

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks.